# Using spread {tidyr} function, getting "Error in map(.variables, id_var, drop = drop) : object 'map_impl' not found"

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm using:

Windows 7 64-bit

R version 3.4.2, 32-bit

Rstudio version 1.1.383

I'm trying to use the spread function to pivot a column's values in to columns but I get the error "Error in map(.variables, id_var, drop = drop) : 
  object 'map_impl' not found"

I've got these libraries loaded:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(curl)
library(readr) #added for csv read
library(dplyr) #added to pivot the data to vertical format
library(tidyr) #added to pivot the data to vertical format
```

At this time, I'm getting warnings about these packages being built under R version 3.4.3 or 3.4.4.

Example of the issue:

```
stocks <- data.frame(
  time = as.Date('2009-01-01') + 0:9,
  X = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
  Y = rnorm(10, 0, 2),
  Z = rnorm(10, 0, 4)
)

pivot2 <- stocks %>%
  spread(time,X)
```

Which returns the error described above.

I've run this same code on my personal laptop that is running 64-bit R version 3.5 and it works without issue, which leaves me wondering if it's a version issue.

Unfortunately, my workplace has a strict deployment policy on R and I cannot individually update my version, or even install a copy of R to my actual computer, so I'm unable to see if updating resolves the issue.

In searching for this issue I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51509236/error-object-map-impl-not-found) on SO but with no examples and therefore no real answer.

Any information about this error would be helpful, and let me know if there is additional information needed to resolve the issue.  Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest you start a brand new R session, you run this piece of code using ONLY the packages required (`dplyr` and `tidyr`) and if you still have a problem you should update R to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks @AntoniosK, did this just now, only loaded dplyr and tidyr, got the same error with the example.  Unfortunately, can't update my versions of anything.  The next time the IT group updates the version, I'll update this question with new results.

Comment: It would obviously be better to figure out the root of the issue, but if you can't and you still need to do this transformation, `library(reshape2);
stocks %>% dcast(X ~ time)` will do the same thing.

Comment: @Ryan, thanks!  Was just going to checkout reshape then refreshed and saw your answer.  Didn't get the error using your solution, so probably an issue with tidyr?  Anyway, will use reshape and move on now.